# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre function name() y var name = function() en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Yo en mis principios como programador (en JavaScript mejor dicho) declaraba las funciones de esta forma:

```
function name(){}
```

Pero luego comencé a ponerlas de la siguiente forma:

```
var name = function(){};
```

Pero sinceramente no sé que cuál es la diferencia entre ambas o si hay alguna ventaja de una sobre la otra.

Comment: Hay un análisis interesante en [*Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/). Véase también "Functions are data" en *Object-Oriented JavaScript*, Second Edition, pág. 97 ([Google Books](http://bit.ly/2bRHzu6)).

Answer (score 4):

La principal diferencia es que la definición `var name = function(){};`la función no está lista para usar hasta que el código se ejecute.

Es decir si realizas lo siguiente,

```
name() // se imprime "hola"
function name(){ console.log("hola") }
```

Y si en cambio realizas lo siguiente

```
name() // nos da => TypeError: undefined is not a function
var name = function(){ console.log("hola") };
```

Lo interesante con la segunda opción es que dependiendo del flujo o lo que quieras podrías definir la función de una forma u otra. Ejemplo:

```
var name = function(){ console.log("hola") };
if (condicion) {
   name = function(){ console.log("chau") };
}
```

Comment: Detalles en pregunta en inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn